# open browser link in the same desktop

Tags: macos, desktop, window-manager, web-browser

Is there a way to force opening a URL in the same desktop, when there is no browser  window yet in the active desktop ?

(like in linux)

this solution https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4995042 does not work for me

thanks

ps: on macOS 12.4